# How to make box arrows using css3?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make this arrows in my site:

[image]

[image]

How can I make this one using css3 having a transparent background?

Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific in what regard. You could use <img> image tag..Just edit the image in paint.net to remove white areas

Comment: Use the images which you have posted here. using css could reduce the performance when compare with using images.

Comment: Thanks Mr_Green and Palmer for replay. When I use images I'm not reducing the performance? So, images are better than css?

Comment: @mayconbelfort, Unless you use excessively large images, yes, images are better performance-wise. However, you can of course do more with CSS. E.G. http://jsfiddle.net/N3Hew/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a font for the arrows and then CSS for the circles.

See working fiddle with Font Awesome:
http://jsfiddle.net/t2UA5/1/

```
<div class="halfCircleLeft"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></div>
<div class="halfCircleRight"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
```

CSS

```
.halfCircleRight{
     height:90px;
     width:45px;
     border-radius: 0 90px 90px 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 90px 90px 0;
     -webkit-border-radius:  0 90px 90px 0;
     background:transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 0px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    4px 0px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         4px 0px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75); 
    position:relative;
    z-index:50;
}

.halfCircleLeft{
     height:90px;
     width:45px;
     border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
     -moz-border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
     background:transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 0px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    -4px 0px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         -4px 0px 25px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
        position:relative;
    z-index:50;
}

.fa.fa-angle-left {
    color:#27367A;
    font-size:30px;
        position:relative;
    z-index:150;
    top:30px;
    left:20px;
}
.fa.fa-angle-right {
    color:#27367A;
    font-size:30px;
        position:relative;
    z-index:150;
    top:30px;
    left:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code help you :

```
<div class="arrow-bg">
   <div class="arrow">
   </div>
</div>

.arrow-bg {
border-radius:30px;
box-shadow:-10px 0 8px #EDEDED;
padding:20px 15px;
width:30px;
}
.arrow {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;  
border-right:10px solid blue; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple arrow and now you can add shadows and so on...

```
<div id="some_div">some text</div>
<div id="arrow"></div>

#arrow {
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right:10px solid white;
    float: left;
    height: 1px;
}
```